# How to refresh 2 iframes with one link/button using html/js

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, refresh

I'm new here and like to know how to refresh 2 different iframes on one page.

I found something on google using getElemenById. But it has to work in firefox and firefox has some problems with Id's.

thanks in advance.

```
<form action="managecartform.html" onclick="deleteAllCookies();"><button type="submit" >Empty cart</button></form>
```

Comment: please update your html with the actual html you have and specify WHEN you want to reload the iframes and whether or not you want to submit the form to the current page

Answer (score 0):

What does your form have to do with iframes?

Do you mean this? Load the managecartform into one frame and reload the other?

```
<form action="managecartform.html" target="iframe1" 
onsubmit="deleteAllCookies(); window.frames[0].location.reload(1);">
<input type="submit" value="Empty cart"/>
</form>
<iframe name="iframe0"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

firefox doesn't have problems with ids -- 99% of the time it's because you've either got a missing id or you've duplicated an id.

ids must be unique throughout the entire document.

to answer your question though:

```
<iframe id="frame1"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2"></iframe>

<input type="button" onclick="refreshFrames()" value="refresh frames" />

<script type="text/javascript">
     function refreshFrames(){
          frame1 = document.getElementById('frame1');
          frame2 = document.getElementById('frame2');
          if(frame1.contentDocument){
              frame1.contentDocument.location.reload(true);
              frame2.contentDocument.location.reload(true);
          } else {
              frame1.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
              frame2.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
          }
     }
</script>
```

(For IE, you might have to use contentWindow instead of contentDocument depending on the version of IE you're trying to support)

Comment: let me rephrase the first part: in the 10 years i've been doing client side development, i've never run into an issue where document.getElementById() didn't work in firefox EXCEPT when I was either missing the id attribute on the element, or had two items with the same id attribute.

Comment: I tried your code but when i open the error console from firefox i get the message: frame1 = null.          the iframe is coded as folows: <iframe src="pages/cart.html" class="cart" id="cart123" name="cart"/></iframe>